# How can I exhaustively scrape the contents of a web directory?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, web-scraping

## TLDR:

How do I efficiently determine a sequence of queries that give back every result from a directory of names, given that responses to each query are limited to a small fraction of the number of entries in the whole directory?

## Goal

I have been tasked with scraping all information from a number of university directories. These directories consist of faculty and staff members and each person has information that I am interested in collecting (name, email address, title, department, etc.). For most directories, my goal is to get URLs which corresponds to each member of the directory, so that information about that person can be gathered individually. Thus, for my purposes, getting a list of every name in the directory is sufficient.

For some of these directories, I am required to make a search query that then returns some results (others display all results at once). Usually, I am given the option to search by one (or several) fields, including first name, last name, and department, among others. Unfortunately, queries often have a maximum results limit which prevents me from simply searching A, B, C, etc.

### How are queries interpreted?

Across the board, all queries are case-insensitive. Note that directories variously interpret search queries. I have seen three interpretations:

Assume the following toy directory: `["Abby", "Abraham", "Alb", "Babbage"]`

**1. Implicit following wildcard**: results that start with the query are returned

In this case, searching "ab" would return "Abby" and "Abraham" but not "Babbage".

**2. Implicit double wildcard**: results that contain the query are returned

Here, searching "ab" would return "Abby", "Abraham", and "Babbage".

**3. Fuzzy matching**: results that contain or are close to the query are returned

In this case, searching "ab" would return all four names.

## Algorithm

From these interpretations, I designed an algorithm which assumes its queries are treated with implicit following wildcards. I chose this interpretation because, when the same queries are interpreted as having an implicit double wildcard or with fuzzy matching, the results will be a superset of the expected interpretation. Thus, the same algorithm could be applied to all situations.

Potential caveat: with the double wildcard or fuzzy matching interpretations, there will be many more results for each query, requiring many more queries to cover the whole directory at the same number of maximum results.

### Algorithm specification

The algorithm proceeds as follows:

1. Set the last name query to be `a`.

2. Make the last name query.

2a. If not over the results limit, save the results to the results set and increment the last character of the last name query (e.g. go from `a` to `b` or `apple` to `applf`) and return to step 2 (note that this could induce a carrying process such as from `azzz` to `b`). If this increment overflows, the search is complete and you can should skip to step 4. If over the results limit, continue to step 2b.

2b. Set the first name query to be `a`.

2c. Query the first name and the last name at the same time.

2d. If not over the results limit, save the results to the results set, increment the last character of the first name query, and return to step 2c. If this increment overflows (e.g. if a first name query of `z` is under the results limit), set the first name query to be blank and continue to step 3. If over the results limit, add an `a` to the end of the first name query and return to step 2c.

3. Add an `a` to the end of the last name query and return to step 2.

4. Return the set of results.

### Python implentation

Here is the above algorithm, implemented in Python pseudocode. I included helper functions such as `make_query()`, `increment()`, and `append_a()`.

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
names = get_random_names(n=10000)
results_limit = 25

def make_query(first="", last=""):
    print("Querying for the following:")
    print("first:", first)
    print("last:", last)
    results = set()
    for n in names:
        f, l = n
        if f.lower().startswith(first) and l.lower().startswith(last):
            results.add(n)
    if len(results) > results_limit:
        print("Too many results")
        print()
        return set(), True
    else:
        print("Success! This gave " + str(len(results)) + " results")
        print()
        return results, False

def increment(q):
    ql = [chars.index(c) for c in q]
    while ql[-1] == len(chars) - 1:
        del ql[-1]
        if len(ql) == 0:
            return ql, True
    
    ql[-1] += 1
    return "".join([chars[i] for i in ql]), False

def append_a(q):
    ql = [chars.index(c) for c in q]
    ql.append(0)
    return "".join([chars[i] for i in ql])


def search_directory(field="last", fixed_last=None):
    all_results = set()
    query = "a"
    num_queries = 0

    while True:
        if field == "last":
            query_results, over_limit = make_query(last=query)
            num_queries += 1
        elif field == "first":
            query_results, over_limit = make_query(first=query, last=fixed_last)
            num_queries += 1
        if not over_limit:
            all_results = all_results.union(query_results)
            query, is_finished = increment(query)
            if is_finished:
                return all_results, num_queries
            continue
        elif over_limit and field == "last":
            first_name_results, first_num_queries = search_directory(field="first", fixed_last=query)
            num_queries += first_num_queries
            all_results = all_results.union(first_name_results)

        query = append_a(query)

results, num_queries = search_directory()
print(results)
print("Number of results:", len(results))
print("Number of entries in directory:", len(set(names)))
print("Accuracy:", str(len(results)/len(set(names))))
print("Number of queries:", num_queries)
print("Missed names:")
print(set(names) - set(results))
```

### Search example

To help people understand this algorithm better, I am providing an example sequence of queries and responses. For brevity, assume the directory consists of the following names only (in `(first, last)` format):

`[("aa", "bac"), ("aa", "bba"), ("aa", "aaa"), ("ab", "bc"), ("b", "bab"), ("ccc", "a")]`

Additionally, the results limit will be two (searches can have at most two results). Finally, assume that our queries will be interpreted as having wildcards following them. Here are the queries the algorithm performs:

| # | Last name query | First name query | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | - | Under results limit |
| 2 | b | - | Over results limit |
| 3 | b | a | Over results limit |
| 4 | b | aa | Under results limit |
| 5 | b | ab | Under results limit |
| 6 | b | ac | Under results limit |
| 7 | b | b | Under results limit |
| 8 | b | c | Under results limit |
| 9 | ba | - | Under results limit |
| 10 | bb | - | Under results limit |
| 11 | bc | - | Under results limit |
| 12 | c | - | Under results limit |

And the results:
 `{('aa', 'bba'), ('b', 'bab'), ('aa', 'bac'), ('aa', 'aaa'), ('ab', 'bc'), ('ccc', 'a')}`

### Issues

With these 12 queries, I was able to get every name in the database. However, I have concerns with the efficiency of the algorithm. I tested it on random subsets of names from the 2015 Facebook leak, and I was able to achieve 100% completeness or greater on databases of thousands of names. From what I can tell, it took as many as 18,000 queries to retrieve a database of 9,000 names and 240,000 queries to retrieve a database of 90,000 names.

This is not a desirable level of performance, given that many of the directories I need to run the algorithm on have on the order of 10,000 entries, and each query could take as much as a second or two. More problematically, when adapting this algorithm to use the double wildcard interpretation, it takes as many as 280,000 queries to recover an 8,000 entry database, which is clearly too many.

Is there a more efficient way for me to achieve full coverage, both in the case of the following wildcard and the double wildcard interpretation?

## Problem restatement

How do I efficiently determine a sequence of queries that give back every result from a directory of names, given that responses to each query are limited to a small fraction of the number of entries in the whole directory?

Comment: If you feel you may need headings and a lr;dr, your question may not be a good fit for stackoverflow... see [ask].

Comment: The TLDR is all you really need to answer the question. The rest is to explain my (unsuccessful) attempts to solve it.